# Manual GLU.gluUnproject

Tags: opengl, shaders, matrix, lwjgl, picking

Before I used GLU.gluUnproject to calculate my picking ray in my OpenGL game. Recently I switched to my own calculated matrices, and now I can forget the gluUnproject.

How can I calculate the picking ray with my own matrices?

My picking ray code (for the fixed pipeline):

```
public Ray getPickingRay() {
    FloatBuffer modelBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);
    FloatBuffer projBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(16);

    glGetFloat(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelBuffer);
    glGetFloat(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projBuffer);

    IntBuffer viewPort = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(16);
    glGetInteger(GL_VIEWPORT, viewPort);

    FloatBuffer obj_pos = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(3);
    float middleX = (Display.getWidth() / 2)-0.01f;
    float middleY = (Display.getHeight() / 2)-0.01f;
    GLU.gluUnProject(middleX, middleY, 1.0f, modelBuffer, projBuffer, viewPort, obj_pos);

    Vector3f objPos = new Vector3f(obj_pos.get(0), obj_pos.get(1), obj_pos.get(2));

    Vector3f.sub(objPos, game.player.position, objPos);

    return new Ray(game.player.position, objPos);
}
```

At first I thought I just could use my own model- and projection matrix, but I have not found a way to manually calculate the GL_VIEWPORT intBuffer.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you'd get from `glGet` with `GL_VIEWPORT` (that you were previously passing to `glUnProject`) are the same values you have previously used to define the OpenGL viewport size using [glViewport](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glViewport.xml).

If, as noted in the referenced documentation, you've never called `glViewport` yourself, the width and height of the viewport are the dimensions of the (client area) of the window (and the X and Y values are both zero). You can therefore use the bounds of the client area of your window in the computation of your pick ray where glUnProject would have used the `GL_VIEWPORT` values.

Comment: So if I create an empty intbuffer and fill it with x, y, width, height in that order I have the GL_VIEWPORT?

Comment: So long as you have not modified the GL viewport with glViewport elsewhere, yes.